# The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context

Tags: dns, sql-server, iis

We have an application hosted on IIS. There are three servers in play here:

- TEST IIS application server
- PROD IIS application server
- SQLServer that hosts the DB for both application instances

These servers where migrated recently, and everything worked fine until the power went down in the old site and interestingly enough only the TEST server threw the exception

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The target
>   principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.

while the PROD server worked fine.

I am trying to find out why that is. Both have Integrated Security set to true (in the web.config) and they are accessing the same server. 

Is there a way I can get the IP of the server where the authentication takes place?

Comment: Some apps must initialize **after** the database is online, otherwise it won't run afterwards even if the database is online (I have some like these on my environment). Is it possible that you have some app like this and the recovery of your servers happened in this order: 1st TEST IIS 2nd SQL Server 3rd PROD IIS? If so, could you reboot your TEST IIS server now that the database is online?

Comment: Don't think that is the case, initially everything was running for some time before the power went out. The outage was at the old site, the app relies ( or shouldn't be relying) on nothing from the old site. I think it is still doing SQLServer "Windows Authentication" using the old server somehow!

Comment: Where did you get the error message from: IIS server or SQL Server? Is the new site under the same Domain of the old one? Cause if you think your TEST IIS is pointing to the old SQL Server you could change the `hosts` file adding the old SQL server DNS pointing to the new SQL Server IP.